# Detect periods of gradual decreases in time-series data

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection

I have some time-series data sets in which, in principle, two types of event are possible: the signal can instantaneously jump up or down; or there can be a gradual decrease in the signal. I want to detect the regions featuring only the gradual decreases, without detecting the large jumps in signal strength. Below is an example of this, showing: one gradual decrease of interest from ~392-398 s; a jump back at ~398 s; a pause from ~398-400 s; and a second gradual decrease of interest from ~400-404 s.

[image: an image of a sample data set, showing one gradual decrease of interest from ~392-398 s; a jump back at ~398 s; a pause from ~398-400 s; and a second gradual decrease of interest from ~400-404 s]

So far, I have tried various methods to pick out these features, including low-pass filters and matched filters, but I've struggled to get something with enough fidelity to mark the start and end-points accurately. I think the matched filter was the closest I've got, but since I'm only looking for a slight change in gradient of the data the filter wasn't sufficiently discriminatory.

My question is similar to that in the thread [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/391430/detect-gradual-change-in-time-series-data), but a) I specifically want to filter out quick changes, unlike in that question; and b) the question there was closed without an answer because the question had insufficient detail, so I'm trying my own here.

Comment: Can you provide the data for plot which is shown? That would allow someone to take a proper crack at it

Comment: There also looks to be a gradual *increase* before the first decrease. How should that be handled?